# Ionic android app is very slow in accessing REST api to server when run on a real device

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I test the `ionic` app on a real device the `REST` calls are taking too much time, which actually will prompt the user to close the app. But on the developing stage, it works fine on local browsers using the command "`IONIC SERVE`". The same internet wifi connection is using on both android phones and developing computers. A sample rest Call used is

```
$http.get(newsurl).success(function(data){
$scope.news=data;

})
```

Did anybody face a similar problem?

Comment: Add logging of the operations and run logcat with the -v time option, and/or setup a packet sniffer to times stamp the traffic.  Then see where the delays are.

Answer (score 0):

There was an infinite scroll option in a window which was creating too many ajax requests to server. and when i moved between different tabs in the app number ajax calls was increasing, Too much ajax request are getting blocked.
I just showed a loading window while processing an ajax request so that users cannot move between tabs while ajax request are processing